# How can I calculate odo sum in pandas based on voltage drop from 54 to 52 and 51 to 48?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas data frame columns one is the voltage and another one is the odo reading i want to sum the odo based on voltage decreasing from 54 to 52 what is the odo sum and 51 to 48 what is the odo sum and so on

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'voltage': [54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 49.34, 49.00, 48.88, 48.34, 48.10, 47.70, 47.34, 47.10, 46.98, 46.23, 46.10, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 49.34, 49.00, 48.88, 48.34, 48.10, 47.70, 47.34, 47.10, 46.98, 46.23, 46.10, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23],
    'odo': [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

expecting result when voltage drops from 54 to 52 that is this entire set54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10 what is the odo sum 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20 and next cycle  51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 49.34, 49.00 and corresponding odo 3, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7 thease values sum i need
expected result
54 to 52 odosum 57,
51 to 49 odosum 39, and so on

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected result?

Comment: edited my question from 54 to 52 range of voltage values what is the sum of odo

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column in the dataframe indicating the voltage range using `pd.cut`, and then use `groupby` to group by the voltage range and calculate the sum of odo reading for each group. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'voltage': [54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 49.34, 49.00, 48.88, 48.34, 48.10, 47.70, 47.34, 47.10, 46.98, 46.23, 46.10, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 49.34, 49.00, 48.88, 48.34, 48.10, 47.70, 47.34, 47.10, 46.98, 46.23, 46.10, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23, 49.98, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, 51.88, 51.43, 51.23, 50.67, 50.23],
    'odo': [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# define the voltage ranges
bins = [48, 51, 54, 57]

# create a new column indicating the voltage range for each row
df['voltage_range'] = pd.cut(df['voltage'], bins=bins)

# use groupby to group by the voltage ranges and calculate the sum of odo readings for each group
odo_sums = df.groupby('voltage_range')['odo'].sum()
print(odo_sums)
```

This will output:

```
voltage_range
(48, 51]    209
(51, 54]    163
(54, 57]    254
Name: odo, dtype: int64
```

So the sum of odo readings for voltage decreasing from 54 to 52 is 254, for 51 to 48 is 163, and so on.

Comment: actually the bins what you mentiond 57 values is not in voltage data ,what iam expecting is i want to caliculate when voltage drops from 54 to 52 that is 54.8, 54.5, 53.90, 53.88, 53.50, 53.25, 53.10, 52.98, 52.65, 52.10, from this cycle of value wants to sum 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, same for remaing cyclles that is 51 to 49 and 48 to 46

Comment: edited my question kindly look on to it